# How do I deploy a node app on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I followed these steps: https://developers.google.com/deployment-manager/nodejs

But I don't really know where to go from there...how do I actually deploy my node application? Where is the node code? It's not on my machine, I don't think. So, how do I edit it?

I tried connecting to the shell, installing a node app with yo, and serving it to port 9000 with grunt, and then allowing that port with

```
gcutil --project <project-id> addfirewall http9000 --allowed tcp:9000
```

and navigating to the address, but it didn't work. However, navigating to 8080, which is what the tutorial said to do gets me Hello World, but I don't know where that code is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Taking look at the star-up script in the vm, I notice that your have this ' DIR=/srv/www FILE=hello.js...', so I found the source at '/srv/www/hello.js'